# MySQL DB or JDBC driver not handling LocalDate.MAX

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc

I am trying to run a query with a start date and end date as parameters, which may be null.

MySQL - the DB or the JDBC driver or in combination - cannot handle null values by which I mean, the SQL `AND endDate <= null` excludes every row.

So I am trying to use `startDate >= LocalDate.MIN` which works well for the "no start date".

But `endDate <= LocalDate.MAX` doesn't work to allow any date. This is the SQL template:

```
String strStmt = "SELECT d.forecastId, d.valueDate, d.value " +
        "FROM data d " +
        "WHERE d.forecastId = ? " +
        "AND valueDate >= ? " +
        "AND valueDate <= ? " +
```

and this is the variable allocation:

```
if (startDate == null) {
    statement.setObject(2, LocalDate.MIN);
} else {
    statement.setObject(2, startDate.toInstant().atZone(
            ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
}
if (endDate == null) {
    statement.setObject(3, LocalDate.MAX);
} else {
    statement.setObject(3, endDate.toInstant().atZone(
            ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
}
try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) { 
...
```

and this is the SQL which it produces (via P6Spy):

```sql
SELECT valueDate FROM data d WHERE d.forecastId = 52010 
AND valueDate >= '-999999999-01-01' 
AND valueDate <= '+999999999-12-31'
```

This doesn't work, I get no rows.

If I then change it to something less extreme:

```
if (endDate == null) {
    statement.setObject(3, LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01"));
...
```

I see the following in the P6Spy logging:

```sql
SELECT valueDate FROM data d WHERE d.forecastId = 52010 
AND valueDate >= '-999999999-01-01' 
AND valueDate <= '2019-01-01'
```

and the query works fine, except of course at some point in the future.

Is this some sort of overflow in MySQL? Should I use `LocalDate.MAX` differently or what can I use instead of `LocalDate.MAX`?

I don't wish to revert to

```
    statement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

which produces the following:

```sql
AND valueDate <= '17-Aug-94'
```

which doesn't work either - maybe a Y2K or Year 2038 bug? P6Spy is not helping by displaying it with its own unhelpful format.

Comment: Can you change the query itself, i.e. dynamically only include the other date comparison if the date is not null?

Comment: Read the doc? _The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'._ https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/date/

Comment: Not related to your problem, but Connector/J 6.0.4 is a development version for the abandoned version 6 of Connector/J, it is not a production ready version. The last released version is 5.1.44. The latest development release is 8.0.8 (but that version is not production-ready!).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel oh right. I just grabbed 6.0.6 because IntelliJ auto-completed it in the pom.xml. I had some other issues simultaneously with character encoding with related bugs in the mysql bugzilla so I tried to change it, but IntelliJ seems to hang on to its jars for grim death which makes changing versions tedious. I'm now trying out mariadb connector/j 2.1.2

Answer (score 5):

## Exceeding limits of the data type `DATE` in MySQL

The data type [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) in MySQL 5.7 is limited to a much smaller range of values than the [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) type. Quoting from that doc, (emphasis mine):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The **supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'**.

In contrast, [`java.time.LocalDate.MAX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#MAX) is the date +999999999-12-31. The year 999999999 is well beyond the year 9999.

If your goal is recording a particular date far in the future as a stand-in for an unknown or indeterminate date, choose one not quite so far out. Or use NULL, but neither [Dr. Chris Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date) nor I recommend using NULL.

Date-time capabilities vary *widely* amongst various databases. The SQL standard barely touches on the subject. So you must carefully read the documentation of your particular database to learn the limits and the behavior of that product. Likewise, your JDBC driver.

Comment: Nice post :) The application I'm working on is a forecasting app that serves an Excel add-in, Python, r and other clients. One of the load tests we ran (admittedly not for real use) involved adding 250,000 daily dates into the future (2684). I suppose 9999 is ridiculously far in the future, but without much effort, we've already got a quarter of the way there. I'll see if I can find a MySQL max date constant in the JDBC library that I can use instead of LocalDate.MAX. If the app is ever re-written, I figure it would make sense just to abandon the DATE type. I see there's no BIGDATE.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not intending to filter out rows that have a `null` value in `valueDate`, it seems that you're trying to create a condition that always evaluates to `true` when either the start or end date in the query is `null`. I think it would be simpler to just omit the (redundant) comparison in the `null` end/start date case, by generating the SQL dynamically:

```
String strStmt = "SELECT d.forecastId, d.valueDate, d.value " +
        "FROM data d " +
        "WHERE d.forecastId = ? ";

if (startDate != null) {
    strStmt += "AND valueDate >= ? ";
}
if (endDate != null) {
    strStmt += "AND valueDate <= ?";
}
```

Then, after creating the statement, you would dynamically add the correct number of date parameters:

```
int index = 1;

statement.setInt(index++, forecastId);

if (startDate != null) {
    statement.setObject(index++, startDate.toInstant().atZone(
            ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
}
if (endDate != null) {
    statement.setObject(index, endDate.toInstant().atZone(
            ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
}

try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
 //...
```

Comment: No, I can't change the query. I have to do a quick syntax change for the embedded SQL in my current app's Java to change from SQL Server to MySQL and this part is used by a lot of methods. If I don't find a sensible value for the constant, I'll look at spending time on refactoring the whole module later.